# Seeking shapefiles of buildings in Qingdao, China?

Tags: data, china

We are starting a new esearch project in China and I've been looking for a while and the closest thing I can find is buildings of Beijing. But I need Qingdao not Beijing. It seems like I will have to use satellite images to generate the buildings through machine learning pattern recognition. Which I would rather not do because I dont know how to do that lol.

Anyone got any tips?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for OpenDataSE.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the Quick OSM plugin for QGIS.

Input the following information shown in the image below and hit run query. Once this has ran you'll get some temporary layers showing your buildings. You can then save this as you see fit.

[image]

Comment: Yes I tried this but the building data is very incomplete though.